# set specific record to first in row laravel query builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to set all records `order by FIELD_NAME` but only 1 record with specific `id` need to be remain at first.

How can i achieve this using `laravel query builder`

My current query is like,

```
$orders =Order::orderBy('status', 'desc')
  ->where('status','<>',5)
  ->paginate(10);
```

And i want id=123 stay at first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `orderByRaw` and simple sql condition:

```
        $orders = Order::orderByRaw('IF(id = 123, 0,1)')->orderBy('status', 'desc')
            ->where('status', '<>', 5)
            ->paginate(10);
```